# How to change Loopback accessToken from queryString to Bearer Token

Tags: node.js, jwt, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

I'm working on using Loopback to create a mock service. I need this mock service to authenticate using Bearer Tokens. Something like this:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: BEARER ABCDEFG' 'http://localhost:3000/api/Puppies'
```

At the moment, authentication is handled out of the box using a query string like this:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:3000/api/Puppies?access_token=ABCDEFG'
```

Is there a way I can change the default authentication to the former?

Answer (score 0):

In order to authenticate using Bearer tokens, you can use Loopback `@loopback/authentication` package. If you want to use JWT, you need  `@loopback/authentication-jwt` extension.